# Deserialize JSON (Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I need a little help with json deserialization. It's the first time I'm using Json, so I have just a little knowledge about it.

I get the following string using a webclient:

```
[{"name": "somename", "data": [[72, 1504601220], [null, 1504601280], ..., [125, 1504605840]]}]
```

and tried to serialize it with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(jsonstring)
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class TestObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string TargetName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data"]
    public List<?????> DataPoints {get; set;}
}
```

How do I need to design my class to get the data values in some kind of collection so each entry contains the two values inside a bracket?

Thx for your patience and help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your data is a list of arrays containing nullable integers (by the looks of it)

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data"]
public List<int?[]> DataPoints {get; set;}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I got a JsonSerializationException ("Cannot deserialize the current JSON array [...] because the type requires a JSON object [...] to deserialize correctly.")

Comment: @ErikT. Looks like youve copied some JSON string from the console which includes this char (`...`) instead of the real actual JSON text. See this live example for it working without that character: http://rextester.com/ESC67816

Comment: Stupid me used <TestObject> insead of <List<TestObject>>. It's working properly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this website: http://json2csharp.com/
This website can save a lot of your time if you have just a plain JSON text. It helps you convert it to C# object, although you still have to double check it.

```
var data = "[{\"name\": \"somename\", \"data\": [[72, 1504601220], [null, 1504601280], [125, 1504605840]]}]";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestObject>>(data);

public class TestObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string TargetName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public List<int?[]> DataPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that website recommendation. Seems pretty useful, especially for larger strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a some solution for this, C# 7.0 also supports **ValueTuple** such as this example.

```
List<(int? ,int?)> DataPoints { get; set; }
// if it not work try this.
List<List<int?>> DataPoints { get; set; }
```

If your json inner array elements count is equal to 2, so can assume to you use the value tuples.

Assume it is helpful for you.